# How to make a cos function into a sin function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, functions, trigonometry

I need to convert this equation into a sin function:
f(x) = 12 cos(2x + 1) − 3
I know cos(x)= sin (pi/2 -x) but other than that I dont know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's it.

$f(x) = 12 \cos(2x + 1) − 3$ and $\cos(x)= \sin (\pi/2 -x)$

$\therefore f(x) = 12 \sin(\pi/2-1-2x)-3$

---

Though you could also use: $\cos(A+B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$

... and: $\sin(A+B) = \sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$

It won't come out any neater.

Comment: so if i wanted to set that equal to -1 I get -0.1467 but it says it's wrong.

Comment: You solved for ${\pi \over 2} - 1 -2x$. Did you solve that for $x$?

Answer (score 1):

If you define $y = 2x + 1$ you can write $f(x)$ as: $$f(x) = 12 \cos(y) -3$$ If you now use that $\cos(y)=\sin(\pi/2-y)$ you get: 
$$ f(x)=12 \sin(\pi/2 - y) -3  $$
Using $y = 2x + 1$ you now get:
$$ f(x)=12 \sin(\pi/2 - (2x +1)) -3 $$

Comment: so if i wanted to set that equal to -1 I get -0.1467 but it says it's wrong.

Comment: You mean -1 = 12 sin(pi/2 - (2x+1))-3? -0.1467 is not a solution to that equation.

Comment: yes. I took the one and make it 2/2 so I could subtract pi from it to get 1.14159/2. I then solved for x

Comment: can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get f(x)=g(x). This is a sinusoidal problem and I need to find the primary solution x so I need to make cos into sin. so I did -1=12sin(pi/2 - 2/2 -2x)-3. I add three to both sides and divide by 12 so get 0.16667=sin(1.14159/2 - 2x). I then took the arcsin to get 0.167448=1.14159/2 - 2x. Multiplied both sides by 2/1.14159 to get 0.293359=-2x. Divided by -2 and got -0.1467

Comment: Ok, pi=3.1416 and you should not multiply by 2/pi.

Comment: I know I combined the pi/2 with the 1 which is where i got the 1.14159/2 from.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But you should not multiply by 2/1.14159 in the second last step.

Comment: oh right....thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following half angle formula:
$$\cos (2y)=1-2\sin^2(y)$$

Is $f(x)$ a known function?

Comment: I have to find the primary solution of the f(x) equation with is f(x)=12cos(2x+1)-3. It is a sinusoidal problem so I need to convert that equation to sin then set that equal to g(x)= -1

Comment: understood now. thanks!